# windows 2008 DNS Website without www?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, iis-7

I have a site on my server that only works with a www.
example: 
http://www.dartmouthplayers.ns.ca/
works but without it, it does not.
http://dartmouthplayers.ns.ca/

But the site's bindings has both listed:

[image]

and the DNS has the blank host record:
[image]

What did I not set right?

It's odd because:
http://dartmouthplayers.ns.ca/ - returns a 500 error
and http://randomtexthere.dartmouthplayers.ns.ca/ - returns a server not found error

thanks!

update: My event log has this error each time I try to access that domain:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP
Date:          9/2/2010 10:36:52 PM
Event ID:      2268
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      WIN-R092323U23
Description:
Could not load all ISAPI filters for site 'DEFAULT WEB SITE'.  Therefore site startup aborted.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP" Guid="{670080D9-742A-4187-8D16-41143D1290BD}" EventSourceName="W3SVC-WP" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">2268</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-09-03T02:36:52.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>10233168</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>WIN-R092323U23</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SiteName">DEFAULT WEB SITE</Data>
    <Binary>02000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: +1 - This is really weird. Just to add to the problem desription, I notice that even linking to static files (http://dartmouthplayers.ns.ca/css/common.css) gives out a 500 error. I've never seen a static file give an error 500 before.

Comment: Are you using any URL rewriting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 500 error is generally associated with an entry in your Event Log which should shed some light on what is happening.  Have a look there, and perhaps update your question with the error, and we can help debug it.

Comment: +1 - exactly. This is an in application error. THe client ends up SOMEWHERE (on the server). Event log should have crash information.

Comment: actually, I spelled it wrong on the binding without the www.
There is no "h" in the name :)

Comment: Well done - glad you got it figured out. Something so simple!

Comment: Hahaha.  I did actually look at the picture to see if that was a problem, but "Darth" parsed so I didn't think any more about it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is good info.  We know DNS is working if you're getting 500s.  A 500 means your client is resolving the correct IP and that the server is throwing a 500 in response to the inbound HTTP request.

@coneslayer:  The screen shot appears to be that of IIS bindings and the title of the post "Windows..."

So I don't believe you have an IIS configuration issue.  It appears, from what we see so far, an application problem.

What is your default HTML file settings and is there some ASP/.NET or JavaScript within that is causing the 500 to be thrown?

Maybe throw up your web.config

Comment: It's not a web.config, default file, or javascript issue.
It just seems like the site is resolving to the server, but NOT the correct website.

Answer (score 1):

Simple but easilly overlooked - do you have other websites running on the IIS?

If so, could one of them accidentally be bound to the same website (the non-www variant)? IIS normally warns you if you try to do this (you get a message about duplicate bindings), but it doesn't actually *stop* you.

Comment: This sounds like a good possibility, if you do have multiple sites configured, try stopping the one that you are trying to have http://dartmouthplayers.ns.ca/ go to and try loading the two domains again. If you still get the 500 but the www. doesn't load, you are getting a different site.

Comment: I just tried this out on my IIS7.5 server and it automatically stopped the website with duplicate bindings when I tried to force it, so this might not actually be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the port and access the site.
I had similar issues with colliding ports and as soon as I change the port things started working. It is totally depended on how to get your domain resolved by the DNS server

Answer (score -1):

HTTP version 1.1 allows multiple websites with different hostnames to share the same IP address (with each one possibly serving different content).  The client sends a "Host:" header indicating which hostname it is trying to access, and the web server has to determine what content to serve for that hostname.

Consequently, independently of the DNS configuration, the web server has to know all the hostnames that can be used to connect to the server, and what content to serve for each one.  So you need to find that configuration in your web server software.

If that's not enough of a hint, tell us what web server software you use.

Comment: -1. He is using IIS. Obvious from the window and the named OS makes it highly likely anyway.

Comment: @TomTom It's not obvious from the window.  There's nothing in the window that says IIS.  There was nothing in the question that said IIS.  The only way it's obvious is if you've used IIS and know what its interface looks like.  I haven't.  Sorry.  I didn't know that was a prerequisite for trying to help here.

Comment: You boviosuly have not a lot of experience with IIS 7 ;)